# Equal Parts Cocktail Measurement

Tags: cocktails

This question may be quite basic.

How do I properly measure ingredients of a Negroni?

Equal parts of each ingredient.

Is it one cap (cocktail shaker cap) of each?

Or equal in terms of mL.

Using my scales:

- Campari, One Cap, 29mL
- Vermouth, One Cap, 27mL
- Gin, One Cap, 23mL

So my question is, should it be "30mL, 30mL, 30mL" or "One cap, one cap, one cap".

Comment: I’m not an expert, but I believe all cocktails are measured by volume not weight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Equal Parts Cocktail Measurement?**

Generally speaking, cocktails are measured by volume not weight.

> Jiggers, cups, and other tools you use to measure out ingredients for a cocktail.
>
> Your options here are simple and few, so this is not terribly complicated.
>
> **Jiggers**
>
> Jiggers are the basic hourglass-shaped stainless-steel measuring device you've seen in many a bar. These are cheap and easy to find in most housewares stores, or online. Typically, the larger cup measures out exactly one jigger, or 1 1/2 ounces. The smaller cup is normally one half jigger, or 3/4 ounces. Be careful, a number of other sizes exist, and you should know what units you're working in.
>
> Many professional bartenders have built up strong proficiency with using these in settings where speed is of an essence. The way to use a jigger most efficiently is to hold it between thumb and forefinger, or between your first thumb and forefinger, or between your first and second fingers, like so:
>
> Hold the jigger steady, and fill it brim-full with your liquid of choice; and then it's easy to quickly tip the contents into a shaker or mixing glass.
>
> Another type of jigger is similar to the hourglass model, but it's mounted on a rod.
>
> **Measuring Cups**
>
> Really, though, it's rare that a home bartender needs to worry about speed. A professional bartender in a high-capacity bar needs to work lightning fast, obviously, but for the home schlub mixing a pre-dinner daiquiri, it's just not necessary.
>
> At home, I almost never use a jigger, unless I just want to practice my jiggering. First of all, not all jiggers are equal: some that might appear to measure a true jigger actually measure 1 1/4 ounces instead of 1 1/2. (The model with the handle, in the picture at top, is one such miscreant.) If I want accuracy in my measuring (and I do), I don't want to have to second-guess the capacity of my tools. My measurer of choice is the Oxo mini angled measuring cup.
>
> I love this darned thing and I use it daily. I even preferred it during my stint as a pro bartender. I only have one problem with it: there's no mark for 3/4 ounces. I usually eyeball it, or if I need more precision, I measure 1/2 and then 1/4 ounces.
>
> I should note, too, that some bartenders don't like measuring amounts as small as 1/4 ounce in these cups. To explain why, I need to mention something called a [meniscus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meniscus_(liquid)). It's the curve in the upper surface of a liquid that's in a container. The reason some people see this as a problem is that the curve can make it difficult to accurately read how close you are to the 1/4-oz. mark.
>
> I have to say I'm not convinced it's always a problem. At most we're looking at a couple of drops of liquid's difference between an accurate measure and an inaccurate measure. If you're measuring a strongly flavored ingredient, such as absinthe or Fernet Branca, a couple of extra drops could affect a cocktail. But for milder tasting ingredients such as lemon juice or simple syrup, it's not going to make a huge difference. - [Cocktail 101: Measuring Utensils](https://www.seriouseats.com/cocktail-101-measuring-utensils-jiggers-cups)

Jiggers are used for accurate measurements and are the foundation of consistent cocktails.

A cocktail jigger is a shot or cocktail measuring cup for bartenders, ranging in sizes of 0.5-2.5 oz. For ease of use, many jiggers have fill lines on the inside or outside with oft-used cocktail or shot glass measurements.

The word jigger can also be used as a unit of measurement in cocktail recipes. If you happen to come across a recipe that calls for a jigger (or jigger shot) of any spirit, that refers to the standard jigger size of 1.5 oz. Shot glasses come in various sizes, but a standard shot glass is also 1.5 oz. So in some instances, a jigger and a shot can refer to the same thing. A smaller 1 oz shot, or the 1 oz side of the jigger, is referred to as a “pony shot.”

> [**Common Jigger Sizes**](https://thecocktailnovice.com/resources/barware-basics/barware-basics-bar-jiggers/)
>
> Generally, these bar measures come in a variety of sizes, including:
>
> - 2oz.
> - 1.5 oz.
> - 1 oz.
> - .75 oz.
> - .5 oz.
> - .25 oz.

[image: Jiggers 101]

[Jiggers 101](https://bevvy.co/articles/jiggers-101/1758)

Comment: A follow-up question. Every time I weigh these spirits. The same volume weighs slightly differently. Is this normal? eg. Gin. Sometimes one cap weighs 23mL. Sometimes 25mL. I weigh as I want to measure standard drinks.

Comment: @ThaliaMitford I cannot speak for all kinds of alcohols, but the common ones (methanol, **ethanol**, and isopropyl alcohol) are a little less dense than water. All three of these have densities of about 0.79 g/cc at standard temperature and pressure, compared to 1.0 g/cc for water. Thus the stronger the liquor the less weight it will per same volume of a less stronger liquor.